# Extra characters after close quote in conditional operator

Tags: tcl

I am using a conditional operator but getting the error "extra characters after close-quote". fdx is a parameter I am trying to pass through the function argument and I am checking if the passed argument is "fdx" or not and based on that the value to be written will be decided.

```
    proc set_ifg_seville2 {port sgmii speed fdx} {
   case $speed {
    10 {
        erf_wr -s dev_$port mac_ifg_cfg tx_ifg [expr ($fdx == "fdx") ? 5:4]

      }

    } #Closing procedure
```

Comment: Did you close your procedure set_ifg_seville2 with a close bracket '}' ? Did you close your case ?

Comment: I guess user3565150 made a typo here. In actual, OP has closed the `proc` properly.  Because, without that OP will end up with `missing close-brace` error message.

Comment: The issue is that since you aren't bracing the expression you pass to `expr`, it is evaluated as a sequence of Tcl arguments. An argument that begins with a quote must end with a quote, and not with a parenthesis as in your code. A space before the parenthesis would have solved it, but bracing the expression is better. Also, the `case` command is deprecated and may disappear in a future version of Tcl: use the `switch` command instead.

Comment: `case`? Woah, old school stuff indeed. Switch to `switch`…

Comment: What version of Tcl has a `case` command?

Comment: Even Tcl 8.6 still has `case`, but it has been deprecated for a long time and is not listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression for the ternary operation in your code should be changed as,

```
erf_wr -s dev_$port mac_ifg_cfg tx_ifg [expr {$fdx == "fdx" ? 5:4}]
```

**Examples :**

```
% set fdx "fdx"
fdx
% set result [expr {$fdx=="fdx" ? "pass" : "fail" }]
pass
% set result [expr {$fdx=="stackoverflow" ? "pass" : "fail" }]
fail
%
```

**Reference :** [expr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm)

Comment: And to extend the example: `expr ($fdx=="fdx") ? "pass" : "fail"` results in the error `invalid bareword "fdx"` because the double quotes are removed by the Tcl parser before the arguments are given to the expr command.